# Issue with Music Bot, !skip command and Directories with Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

When I try debugging my bot using Visual Code Studio, everything works perfectly fine. However when I upload everything to Heroku, the !skip command acts like a !stop command. I've reached out to some people and upon looking at the code, they said that it has something to do with creating a new folder for the Queue, and that I should have the .mp3 file download into the main directory. The only thing is that I've tried changing the directory numerous times in my code and either it doesn't work at all, or it still stops the music completely when I try the !skip command. Does anyone know how this can possibly be fixed?

Here are both of my !play and !queue commands that I've tried updating with the ./Queue and Queue directories.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
async def play(ctx, url: str):

    def check_queue():
        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        if Queue_infile is True:
            DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
            length = len(os.listdir(DIR))
            try:
                first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
            except:
                queues.clear()
                return
            main_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)
            if length != 0:
                song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
                if song_there:
                    os.remove("song.mp3")
                shutil.move(song_path, main_location)
                for file in os.listdir("./"):
                    if file.endswith("mp3"):
                        os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
                voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
                voice.source.volume = 1.00

            else:
                queues.clear()
                return
        else:
            queues.clear()

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        return

    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    try:
        Queue_folder = "./Queue"
        if Queue_infile is True:
            shutil.rmtree(Queue_folder)
    except:
        print("No old Queue folder")

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        get_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        if get_info["duration"] >= 630:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, this video is too long. Please try sending a shorter video.")
            return False

        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 1.00

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {nname[0]}")
```

```
@client.command()
async def queue(ctx, url: str):
    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    if Queue_infile is False:
        os.mkdir("Queue")
    DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
    q_num = len(os.listdir(DIR))
    q_num += 1
    add_queue = True
    while add_queue:
        if q_num in queues:
            q_num +=1
        else:
            add_queue = False
            queues[q_num] = q_num

    queue_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + f"\\song{q_num}.%(ext)s")

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': queue_path,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        get_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        if get_info["duration"] >= 630:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, this video is too long. Please try sending a shorter video.")
            return False

        ydl.download([url])
```

Comment: Have you deployed the latest version of your code into Heroku? And have you uploaded the latest version of your code to github?

Comment: I have deployed the latest version of my code into Heroku, yes. I haven't done that with GitHub, no. A bit new to Heroku, does the code also need to be on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You want to go to the following

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3wsxbMbi5M

I have used this and it worked for me! You still need to do a Procfile and change the worked and the token! When you deploy it should automatically detect that it's python!

This tutorial also shows you how to install ffmpeg to your Heroku server so the bot can run music commands!

Another point doing with Heroku's way is not reliably doing it the Github way is more reliable and works every time.